# How to change the margin title color in a FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

Using Seaborn Facet Grids, how can I change the color of the margin title only?
Note that `g.set_titles(color = 'red')` changes both titles.

```
p = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.displot(data=p, x='flipper_length_mm', 
            col='species', row='sex', 
            facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True)
           )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sns.FacetGrid` class has a private attribute `_margin_titles_texts` which is a list containing the `matplotlib.text.Annotation` objects that make the margin titles. We can iterate through those and call the `set_color` method on each to change the text colour.

```py
import seaborn as sns

p = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
grid = sns.displot(
    data=p,
    x="flipper_length_mm",
    col="species",
    row="sex",
    facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True),
)
for margin_title in grid._margin_titles_texts:
    margin_title.set_color("red")
```

[image: sns.displot of penguins data with red margin titles]