# How to add margin titles to a relplot

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, relplot

Seaborn's FacetGrid has a `margin_titles` kwarg, and its effect is shown in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) e.g.

[image]

How do I similarly add margin titles when using Seaborn's [relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the margin title color in a seaborn FacetGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427241/how-to-change-the-margin-title-color-in-a-seaborn-facetgrid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to use it, but this can be given in a dict in the facet_kws argument.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.relplot(
    data=tips,
    x="total_bill",
    y="tip",
    hue="time",
    col="day",
    row="smoker",  
    facet_kws={"margin_titles": True}
)
```

[image]